# How to find string in List using Scala?

Tags: list, scala

I have a following list-

```
List( naa.60a9800042704577762b45634476337a , 
naa.6d867d9c7acd60001aed76eb2c70bd53 , 
naa.600a09804270457a7a5d455448735330)
```

I want to find a string `42704577762b45634476337a` in above list.
Like first string in list contains given string `42704577762b45634476337a`.

I **dont want to fully match** given string with list elements

How do I find string in list using scala??

Comment: you need to frame the question better. Do you want an exact match or 'ending with' or 'containing'? Also, strings need to be enclosed in double quotes. BTW, its better to mention what you have tried, otherwise it looks like a homework question.

Comment: I want list element containing string

Answer (score 7):

Looking for a substring

```
scala> val x = List("123", "abc")
x: List[String] = List(123, abc)

scala> x.find(_.contains("12"))
res0: Option[String] = Some(123)

scala> x.find(_.contains("foo"))
res1: Option[String] = None
```

If you need an exact match, just replace `contains` with `==`.